# Polymer: how to dynamically change paper-fab size

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to create Polymer FAB (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-fab) dynamically as follow:

```
var navFab = document.createElement("paper-fab");
console.log(navFab.mini)       // output false, which means it is defined
navFab.icon = "arrow-forward"; // this works
navFab.mini = true;            // this doesn't work
console.log(navFab.mini)       // output true
document.body.appendChild(navFab);
```

On screen, the navFab button is of normal size instead of mini size. I put a standard size icon next to it just to compare. This is puzzling me to no end :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [paper-fab](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-fab/blob/master/paper-fab.html) element uses mini to add in a style (width, height = 40px), <strike>this is why it's not able to be resized later by changing the attribute (changes don't automatically reflect to the grabbed style).</strike> **To change mini use setAttribute.**

You can also resize paper-fab by modifying its width and height directly or with a class.

[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JvcoYJSg6p7AIaVMkYxM)

```
<style>
  .small {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
  }
</style>
<paper-fab icon="add"></paper-fab>
<script>
  var fab = document.querySelector('paper-fab');
  fab.addEventListener('tap', function(){
    if( fab.classList.contains('small') ) {
      fab.classList.remove('small');
    } else {
      fab.classList.add('small');
    }
  });
</script>
```

[A note on styling](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/): rules in the parent page have higher specificity than :host rules defined in the element, but lower specificity than a style attribute defined on the host element.

Comment: You can't do it this way. The whole point of shadow DOM is to prevent style bleeding.

Comment: Look at the plnkr example. It works and isn't going into the shadow of paper-fab.

Comment: sweet sorry about that I unintentionally add class `mini` before adding class `small`. Something like <paper-fab mini icon="menu"></paper-fab> Do you mind adding this gotcha for other people? "rules in the parent page have higher specificity than :host rules defined in the element, but lower specificity than a style attribute defined on the host element." quote from here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/

Comment: Do you know how to specific property during createElement? a.k.a specifying mini=true during createElement

Comment: fab = document.createElement('paper-fab'); fab.setAttribute('mini', true);  Also, it turns out you can use setAttribute on a currently existing paper-fab to apply mini without having to worry about classes.